# Python Matrix type

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

```
coordinate_1 = np.array([[(np.cos(0) * np.cos(alpha_radian),
                       np.cos(0) * np.sin(alpha_radian) * np.sin(
                           alpha_radian) - np.sin(0) * np.cos(alpha_radian),
                       np.cos(0) * np.sin(alpha_radian) * np.cos(alpha_radian))],
                     [np.sin(0) * np.cos(alpha_radian),
                      (np.sin(0) * np.sin(alpha_radian) * np.sin(
                          alpha_radian)) - (
                              np.cos(0) * np.cos(alpha_radian)),
                      (np.sin(0) * np.sin(alpha_radian) * np.cos(
                          alpha_radian)) - (
                              np.cos(0) * np.sin(alpha_radian))],
                     [-np.sin(alpha_radian),
                      np.cos(alpha_radian) * np.sin(alpha_radian),
                      np.cos(alpha_radian) * np.cos(alpha_radian)]])
print(coordinate_1)
print(type(coordinate_1))
```

And output

```
[list([(0.7071067811865476, 0.4999999999999999, 0.5)])
list([0.0, -0.7071067811865476, -0.7071067811865475])
list([-0.7071067811865475, 0.5, 0.5000000000000001])]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Why the matrix output always includes a **"list"** at the beginning matrix, how to transfer them to float and I could make a simple matrix multiply.

Comment: Post the code as text not as an image. No one is going to type the whole block of code in this image.

Comment: Thanks for u suggestion

Comment: It's just a typo. The `(` in the `[(` (and the matching `)`) should be deleted.

Comment: Most likely you don't have a consistent number of terms in each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about why these are lists, but I think your bigger problem is that you are trying to impoelement wat seems like a 3d rotation, am I right?

If so, do not use the current implementation, and use instead scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation`.

examples in there:

```
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R
r = R.from_euler('xyz', angles=[-45, 45, 0], degrees=True)
r.as_matrix()
```

This outputs:

```
array([[ 7.07106781e-01, -5.00000000e-01,  5.00000000e-01],
       [-5.55111512e-17,  7.07106781e-01,  7.07106781e-01],
       [-7.07106781e-01, -5.00000000e-01,  5.00000000e-01]])
```

Which is similar to yours. Just play with the angles according to what alpha_radians you are using.

This is way better than writing those headache giving lines :)

Comment: Appreciate it, That is a 3d rotation work, and here is a requirement that we couldn't import any library or APIs besides what has been listed. Only the NumPy and cv2 at the list.